# Remove xmlns:fm from attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I know this kind of question has been answered multiple times, but all the solutions I could find since yesterday didn't work for me.

I have a first XSL file which transforms "custom" XML Framemaker files to DITA file. For some reasons, I have a second XSL file which "cleans" the DITA file obtained:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>

  <xsl:template match="//title/text()[normalize-space()]">
   <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//title/text()[not(normalize-space())]" />

  <xsl:template match="table//footnote"><fn><xsl:value-of select="."/></fn></xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//para"><p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p></xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's a snippet of the output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA 1.2 Topic//EN" "../../dtd/technicalContent/dtd/topic.dtd">
<topic id="Interfaces">
<title>Interfaces</title>
<body>
  <table xmlns:fm="fctfmns.xml" frame="all" colsep="1" rowsep="1">
     <tgroup cols="2" colsep="1" rowsep="1" outputclass="General">
        <colspec colnum="1" colname="1" colwidth="34*"/>
        <colspec colnum="2" colname="2" colwidth="66*"/>
        <thead>
```

But the wanted output would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA 1.2 Topic//EN" "../../dtd/technicalContent/dtd/topic.dtd">
<topic id="Interfaces">
<title>Interfaces</title>
<body>
  <table frame="all" colsep="1" rowsep="1">
     <tgroup cols="2" colsep="1" rowsep="1" outputclass="General">
        <colspec colnum="1" colname="1" colwidth="34*"/>
        <colspec colnum="2" colname="2" colwidth="66*"/>
        <thead>
```

So I want the "attribute" `xmlns:fm="fctfmns.xml"` to be removed. But it seems like it's impossible with all the solutions I tried to include in the cleaning XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="@xmlns:fm">
```

doesn't work, and so do its derivates (with name()). I also tried to declare `xmlns:fm` in `xsl:stylesheet` and to exclude prefix fm, but it didn't work either.

The weirdest thing is that `<xsl:template match="@*">` removes all the attributes, but not `xmlns:fm`.

EDIT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
<!ENTITY nbsp "&#xa0;">]>

<chapter RSID-Document = "BasisRS://OBJ_DOKU/11//001/1//11:63"
RSKM-DocuType = "Manual" RSKM-ProductType = "x"
RSKM-ProductGroup = "x"
RSKM-ProductName = "x" RSIM-Status = "3"
RSKM-Language = "EN" chaptertype = "train" ActivateFilter = "Off">
<title
id = "P_12bcc27e" startposition = "topofpage">x</title>
<module id = "P_67912cfb" xmlns:fm = "fctfmns.xml"
RSID-Component = "BasisRS://OBJ_BAUST/906/EN/001/1//925:2"
RSIM-Checksum = "4ad808b1" RSIM-XRefID = "UID:906:3:9f1e5d1">
    <topic>
        <title id = "P_37e7a2f6" RSIM-XRefID = "UID:906:1:9f1e5c1">x</title>
        <table frame = "all" colsep = "1" rowsep = "1" id = "P_982c71a0"
RSIM-XRefID = "UID:906:2:9f1e5c1">
            <tgroup cols = "2" colsep = "1" rowsep = "1" outputclass = "General">
                <colspec colnum = "1" colname = "1" colwidth = "28*"/>
                <colspec colnum = "2" colname = "2" colwidth = "72*"/>
                <thead>
                    <row rowsep = "1">
                        <entry colname = "1">
                            <para>x</para>
                        </entry>
                        <entry colname = "2">
                            <para>x</para>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <row rowsep = "1">
                        <entry colname = "1">
                            <para>x</para>
                        </entry>
                        <entry colname = "2">
                            <para>x</para>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                    <row rowsep = "1">
                        <entry colname = "1">
                            <para>x</para>
                        </entry>
                        <entry colname = "2">
                            <para>x</para>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                    <row rowsep = "1">
                        <entry colname = "1">
                            <para>x</para>
                        </entry>
                        <entry colname = "2">
                            <para>x</para>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                    <row rowsep = "1">
                        <entry colname = "1">
                            <para>x</para>
                        </entry>
                        <entry colname = "2">
                            <para>x</para>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                    <row rowsep = "1">
                        <entry colname = "1">
                            <para>x</para>
                        </entry>
                        <entry colname = "2">
                            <para>x</para>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                    <row rowsep = "1">
                        <entry colname = "1">
                            <para>x</para>
                        </entry>
                        <entry colname = "2">
                            <para>x</para>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                    <row rowsep = "1">
                        <entry colname = "1">
                            <para>x</para>
                        </entry>
                        <entry colname = "2">
                            <para>x</para>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                    <row rowsep = "0">
                        <entry colname = "1">
                            <para>x</para>
                        </entry>
                        <entry colname = "2">
                            <para>x</para>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                </tbody>
            </tgroup>
        </table>
    </topic>
</module>
</chapter>
```

(Desired output is written above)

Please note that the xmlns:fm namespace is in the module element in the input, but depending on the solutions I test, the xmlns:fm namespace appears either in the table, topic, title, or most often in the tgroup element.

Comment: Well the stylesheet you have posted nowhere has or creates `table xmlns:fm="fctfmns.xml"` explicitly, so any element with a namespace declaration like that in your output is likely to have be copied from the input (which you did not show at all).

Comment: "*The weirdest thing is that `<xsl:template match="@*">` removes all the attributes, but not xmlns:fm.*" No, that's not weird at all. A namespace declaration is not an attribute.

Comment: can you link to some answers that did not work,  then we know what to avoid suggestings?

Comment: Thanks ! Here's the concerned part from the input and the "primary" XSL sheet (before the cleaning one) : http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7kZ

Comment: @Mousey  I tried adding `<xsl:template match="@xmlns:fm">`, modifying `<xsl:template match="node()|@*">` to `<xsl:template match="node()|@*[name()!='xmlns:fm']">`, adding xmlns:fm in xsl:stylesheet and exclude prefix fm, tried functx function "remove-attribute" and it took so much time because I tried all those solutions in both XSL sheets.

Comment: @Frost Please edit your question and show us (1) a small, but complete example of the input XML and (2) the expected output of the transformation. Your mention of 2 XSLT files is confusing, since we don't know which one is being discussed (and I don't see why you need two anyway).

Comment: @michael.hor257k I edited the question, and put the code on xsltransform.net/ncdD7kZ also. I hope this is understandable.

Comment: @Frost A **minimized** example would have been appreciated. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you all for the time you took to answer and for the explanations, I'll prepare my code better for the next questions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you are copying the entire table as is - and this also copies all namespaces that are in scope at that point.

To avoid this, replace this:

```
<xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

with:

```
<xsl:template match="table"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="remove-namespaces"/>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="*" mode="remove-namespaces">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="remove-namespaces"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

**Note**: this is referring to the stylesheet you have posted at http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7kZ - which is *very* different from the one in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much MIchael, it has solved my problem ! Next time I'll try to prepare my question better !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really use an XSLT 2.0 processor and the namespace declaration is copied from your input you can change the template

```
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

to

```
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

See http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYhX for an example where the input has the namespace declaration while the output not because the `xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no"` has not copied it.

With XSLT 1.0 you can use

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

instead of

```
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you ! I checked that msxml.exe supports XSL 2.0 and it actually doesn't ... Is there an equivalency in XSL 1.0 ?

Comment: Instead of `<xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">...</xsl:copy>` try `<xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">...</xsl:element>`.

Comment: I am a beginner at XSL, should I replace "..." by `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>` ? And should I replace "name" by table or something ?

Comment: I have edited the answer and provided the code for two templates that you should use as posted (`name()` is a function call).

Comment: Thank you very much Martin, it works ! Now I will just have to choose between Michael's solution and yours !